# Phonegap inappbroswer events w'ont fire

Tags: events, cordova, inappbrowser

i am using phonegap latest version (3.4.0) and i am trying to implement google aOuth login.
i have added the InAppbroswer plugin to my project, and tryed to use the object events (loadstart,loadstop,loaderor,exit) but is seems that they just dont fire.

my code is very simple, it looks like this:

```
ref  = window.open('http://apache.org', '_blank', 'location=yes');
ref.addEventListener('loadstart', function() { alert('start' ); });
```

i am running the app on [Ripple eulator](http://emulate.phonegap.com/)

i have looked for solution all over the web and have'nt fine one.
so my question is if anybody know of a working sulotion for this?

Thanks for All.

**UPDATE**
. i have tryed inappbroswer plugin on a fresh new Phonegap app i created just for testing this, and the plugin doesn't work! my phone gap version is 3.4.0-0.19.7 and the inappbroswer version is the latest. i installed the plugin via the CLI with the command cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser

Also i have tryred to run this on normal android emulator and nothing good so far..

[the plugin docs is right there](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/blob/master/doc/index.md)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an answer to your question but rather an alternative easy solution, Its easy to use and you don't need to go about listening to browser events. https://github.com/oauth-io/oauth-phonegap

Comment: First of all thanks for the fast answer. i know about this option, but i dont want to use this beacase it's not free. and when my app will get bigger i will have to pey them (;

Comment: Oki, then my next point of call would be to verify that the inappbrowser is actually working, I suspect it is not working. I've seen issues with the inappbrower when certain plugins are installed.

 If this is an ios app, in your compiled code is the following files

CDVInAppBrowser.m
CDVInAppBrowser.h

in ios/(Project Name)/Plugins/org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser

Comment: well i am running my am with ripple, which is a chrome addon for running phonegap apps on chrome. i have tryed inappbroswer plugin on a fresh new Phonegap app i created just for testing this, and the plugin doesn't work! my phone gap version is 3.4.0-0.19.7 and the inappbroswer version is the latest. i installed the plugin via the CLI with the command cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser

Comment: I run the same version of phonegap, my inappbrowser does work. Can you go without ripple?

Comment: well yes. the problem was ripple. it seems that ripple dont support InAppbroswer plugin. thanks.!